# How to design different account for users in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on a personal project where user will be able to register with his email/google/or facebook and that user will be called "basic account".

At the same I want that user to be able to create an online shop. At this point its easy for me , because All I can do is to check if the user is logged in or not, if he is logged in I am going to allow him to create a business/shop Schema and it will refs according to that user.

But, Imagine, someone never registered with the system before and he wants to create a business/shop account where, this where I find a bit difficult to comprehend.

What I did so far is that I create a user Schema such as:

```
const UserSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String},
  googleId: { type: String },
  email: { type: String},
  password: { type: String},
  phone: { type: String},
  avatar: { type: String },
  method: {type: String},

  // role: {type: String},
  roles: [String],
  id: {type: String},
  resetPasswordToken: { type: String },
  resetPasswordExpires: { type: Date },
  usedPasswords: [
    {
      type: String
    }
  ],
  joined: { type: Date, default: new Date() }
});
```

When I am registering this user I assign a role for him and push the role to that array because this user might have two roles, to be able to publish a shop and login to his shop or to use the normal service.

The other option is that, I could just create a new separate Schema and called it "BusinesShema" such as :

```
const ShopSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },

  shopName: { type: String },
  accountType: { type: String },
  shopOwner: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  shopPhone: { type: String },
  addressOne: { type: String },
  addressTwo: { type: String },
  town: { type: String },
  password: { type: String, required:true },
  services: [{ serviceName: { type: String }}],
  shopDrescription: { type: String },
  reviewed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  date_created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

where a new user can just create a new account. but When I tried this, I found that I have to fix my passport jwt handling, because i am using a different model to that of user. Basically when it comes authentication with passport I had create a new strategy because that strategy only checking the UserSchema.

I know this is a bit long and hope someone understood my points. So in a nutshell, how can design a database that is capable of allowing new user to create a new business account and allow existing user to creating a shop account.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't the role functionality working?

Comment: @AvivLo, the role functionality is okay, I dont have a problem, I just want to know how to handle two different scenarios, such as users who only want to register his shop and thats it and also users who already registered with the system and want to create as hop.  Its a bit tricky but hopefull i will try aravind method and I will see. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bit complicated but not an impossible task. You said, you are using Passport JWT Authentication. So please create a new strategy where you need to check in `users` collection whether the user who wants to create a shop is a registered user or not. And at the same time, you have to allow him irrespective of registration into your system and create the JWT token.

In short, create a strategy which allows user to create a shop despite of registering in your system or not.

Hope my comments doesn't confuse you. Please comment if you have any doubts. All the best.

Comment: @Arvind I will try this now and hopefully it would work. It would have been easy if I am able to check the user schema and to check if the input email is found and if its, then we fill in the embeded doc with the shop details. If the email is brand new (i.e) not registered then we create that shop account with that email

Comment: Exactly. But you should have a flag in shop schema which defines whether shop owner is registered or not. It would help in generating reports and subscription modules. Create JWT token based on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, however, I am not really sure if this is the best way to do it, bust as far as the functionality it's pretty close to what I want. However, in terms of clean or good solutions, I have no idea.

So here is code, if someone wants to use it or modify it.

Again I am not entirely sure if it's okay or not but as far as functionality I am happy with it . its fits my scenario perfectly I think

```
 //  Check if there is a record before we register
    let checkDublicates = await Shop.findOne({ email });
    if(checkDublicates){
      return res
          .status(401)
          .send({ error: "This user already registered his shop" });
    }
    // else, we check the user Model and we check for an email that matches the email form req.body
    let userEmail = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (userEmail) {
      // the result from that email will be tested against the Shop email
      let checkShop = await Shop.findOne({ email: userEmail.email });
      // if there is an email, then we say, this user already registed
      if (checkShop) {
        return res
          .status(401)
          .send({ error: "This user already registered his shop" });
      } else {
        //selse we create a new record with that user email and his password.
        const newShop = new Shop({
          // local: {
            shopName,
            email:userEmail.email,
            password:userEmail.password,
            accountType: "shop",

        });
        await newShop.save();
        return res.send({ newShop }); 
      }
    } else {
      // if there is no email in the shop and there no emmail matches the User then we create a bran new Shop
      const newShop = new Shop({
        // local: {
          shopName,
          email,
          password,
          accountType: "shop",

      });

      await newShop.save();
      return res.send({ newShop }); 

    }

  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```